# Spring Boot Multi Module Integration Test

Tags: maven, spring-boot, integration-testing

```
+--------------------------------------+                                 
|  Parent module: com.company.project  |                                 
+----|---------------------------------+                                 
     |                                                                   
     +----- WebApp module: com.company.project <-- @SpringBootApplication
     -                                                                   
     +----- Module A : com.company.project.moduleA                       
     -                                                                   
     +----- Module B : com.company.project.moduleB                       
     -                                                                   
     +----- Module C : com.company.project.moduleC
```

I have a maven structure like one above. Each module is a kind of "service" so it contains many types of components (jpa, web etc). I package the project using webapp module as the entry point.

I want to place integration tests on each service/module since they are independent and I think they "belong" there. Of course when I use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` spring can't find components and run the tests. How should I tackle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `..spring can't find components...` sounds like you have different packages or you might need to define a `@ComponentScan` ...

Comment: Yes ,but module A does not depend on WebApp module so it can't see it's components.